# remove duplicate rows in SQL Server Query

Tags: duplicates

how could we remove or not displaying duplicate row with some conditional clause in sqlserver query, the case look like this one,

```
code    decs
-------------------------
G-006   New
G-006   Re-Registration
```

how can we display just `G-006` with `Re-Registration` Desc, i have tried with this query but no luck either

```
with x as (
            select  new_registration_no,category,rn = row_number()
      over(PARTITION BY new_registration_no order by new_registration_no)
      from  equipment_registrations 
)
select * from x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the same field in the PARTITION BY and ORDER BY clause, the `rn` field will always equal 1.

Assuming that new_registration_no = code and category = decs, you could change the ORDER BY field to be `ORDER BY category DESC` to get that result.  However, that's a pretty arbitrary ORDER BY - you're just basing it on a random text value.  I'm also not 100% sure how well the ROW_NUMBER() function works in a CTE.

A better solution might be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        New_Registration_No, 
        Category, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (
            PARTITION BY New_Registration_No 
            ORDER BY 
                CASE 
                    WHEN Category = 'Re-Registration' THEN 1
                    WHEN Category = 'New' THEN 2
                    ELSE 3
                END ASC ) rn
    FROM Equipment_Registrations
  ) s
WHERE rn = 1
```

You can set the order in the CASE statement to be whatever you want - I'm afraid that without more information, that's the best solution I can offer you.  If you have a known list of values that might appear in that field, it should be easy; if not, it will be a little harder to configure, but that will be based on business rules that you did not include in your original post.